# VFD runs has backup generator, breaks down twice

Tags: generator, vfd, backup

I am Electroman, but very ignorant in electrical knowledge. I have a problem.

We have an irrigation pump connected to a VFD that runs on the electrical grid but is connected to an emergency backup generator. This is the first rainy season with the generator setup. We connected it June 10, and the stronger rainy season starts around the second week of July.

Before the heavy rains started, we had 2-3 outages and worked with the pump running on the generator without problems.

Then one Sunday at night (the pump was not being used) we had an outage because of a storm (without thunder), and Monday morning the VFD was dead with a little puddle of oil in the cabinet. Electrical surge was the explanation.

We replaced the VFD, and one week later we had a storm at night (without thunder and without using the pump) and the next day the same, a puddle of oil under the broken down VFD. A couple of days before it broke down, we did use the pump with the generator successfully.

The explanation again was "electrical surge". However, we have some doubts because:

1. It happened only to the VFD that is connected to the generator, not the other 3 VFDs we have which are not connected to the generator.
2. Too much of a coincidence that this has happened twice one week apart after the connection to the generator was made.

We believe our service providers are missing something.

Here are the equipment specs:

Pump
Baldor Reliance Super-E Motor EJMM2613T, Three-phase 5 HP 230 V 11.6 A

VFD
ABB ACS550-01-017A-2; FREQUENCY CONVERTER

Generator
Generac model PMY15B, prime power 15.8 kVA (12.6 kW), standby power 17.4 kVA (13.9 kW), frequency 60 Hz, rated voltage 220 V, max current 45.7 A

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I there any logical source for the oil? Can it come from the VFD or the drive?

Comment: What do you mean by “drive”? Isn’t the VFD a “drive”? It came from the VFD as it was directly under it in the cabinet, and we could see a drop from one of the cables under the VFD.

Comment: The VFD is an electronic device - I would not expect it to contain ANY oily substance at all. I may be wrong. || [ACS550-01-017A-2 - ABB frequency inverter](https://asb-drives.eu/equipment/freq/abb/acs550/1310/)

Comment: Okay I thought it could be considered a Drive because it is named Variable Frequency Drive. There was an oily texture transparent liquid coming from under the VFD.

Comment: IF the liquid is coming from the VFD the supplier should be able to tell you what it is. I cannot think of any situation where this should happen. And few where it would happen.